# Update-SpSolution, how to know if wsp update is completed

Tags: powershell, upgrade, solution

There is a need to Update/Upgrade an existing `wsp` solution. I notice around 1 minute delay when Update command is run and while `dlls` are copied to `GAC`. I assume this delay could go up/down depending on server usage.

Is there any way I can find out if Upgrade is completed?

Here is my current script -

```
$WSPName   = "MySharePoint.wsp"
$wsppath   = "D:\Deployment\MySharePoint.wsp"
Write-Host 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Starting update for SharePoint solution"
update-SPSolution -Identity $WSPName -LiteralPath $wsppath -GACDeployment

$solution = Get-SPSolution -identity "WilliamsLea.CCM.Products.SharePoint.wsp"
Write-Host $solution.Deployed # Added just for testing
```

Checking `$solution.Deployed` is not helping because it immediately returns true even though `dlls` are not copied in `GAC`.

How can I confirm through PowerShell that `wsp` update is completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code to find deployment status

```
$Name = "MySharePoint.wsp"
Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting..."
$Solution = get-SpSolution $Name
while($Solution.JobExists)
{
    sleep 5
    Write-Host -NoNewline "."
    $Solution = get-SpSolution $Name
}
Write-Host "Deployment Completed"
```

Comment: Hi Amal, one question from ur post - We are checking JobExists property for get-SpSolution command. What is JobExists property checks? Does it checks whether command for getting spsolution details is still running? I tried to look at the summary for this, but couldn't find in msdn - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution.jobexists.aspx

Comment: When we deploy/retract solution it basically creates a TimerJob for doing that job... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsolution.jobexists.aspx

Comment: so we are basically checking whther that temp timer job is still running.. yes?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.